# Different resident set size used when running python code in ipython vs script

Tags: python, memory, ipython

I'm trying to get the memory occupied by a snippet. While running it via script gives same output all the time. But running from ipython terminal gives different results each time I try. I tried with a separate process as well and it's still the same.

Script:

```
> cat /var/tmp/mem1.py
def a(): 
    import os, psutil  
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())  
    before = process.memory_info().rss 
    a = [10]*100000 
    after = process.memory_info().rss 
    print(before, after, after-before) 
                                                       
a()
> python /var/tmp/mem1.py
10035200 10838016 802816
> python /var/tmp/mem1.py
10039296 10842112 802816
> python /var/tmp/mem1.py
10039296 10842112 802816
```

From ipython terminal:

```
In [1]: def a(): 
   ...:     import os, psutil  
   ...:     process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())  
   ...:     before = process.memory_info().rss 
   ...:     a = [10]*100000 
   ...:     after = process.memory_info().rss 
   ...:     print(before, after, after-before) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [2]: from multiprocessing import Process                                                                                                                                                             

In [3]: p = Process(target=a); p.start(); p.join();                                                                                                                                                     
48271360 49057792 786432

In [4]: p = Process(target=a); p.start(); p.join();                                                                                                                                                     
48267264 49053696 786432

In [5]: p = Process(target=a); p.start(); p.join();                                                                                                                                                     
48279552 49033216 753664

In [6]: p = Process(target=a); p.start(); p.join();                                                                                                                                                     
48275456 49041408 765952
```

Can someone help me understand why I'm seeing this behavior in ipython?

Comment: I don't know much about python, but it might help others reproduce the problem if you edit your question to add information about the python and ipython version. It will be important for context if behaviour changes in future versions.